# Составить запрос MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Здравствуйте, в моей коллекции есть записи по типу такого:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a6bd6e4b06b1f23195304"), 
    "name" : "somename",
    "members" : 
    {
        "somemembername1" : { "rank" : 3 }, 
        "somemembername2" : { "rank" : 2 }, 
        "somemembername3" : { "rank" : 1 } 
    } 
}
```

Мне нужно составить запрос в бд так, чтобы он возвращал запись в members которой есть определенный somemembername.
Тоесть, буду искать запись в коллекции по одному значению somemembername.
Одно и то же значение somemember в записях не повторяется никогда.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял:

```
var search = "members." + somemembername;
db.namecollection.findOne({search:{$exists:true}});
```